# getting the value from the other activity using intent doesn't work on the first try

Tags: android

Having problem with this while making a project for our Android subject, i manage to compute bmi then show it to the next activity but on the first try, the name only exist, and on the second try the computed value shows

```js
 btnComp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        btnComp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String name = et.getText().toString();
                String feet = et2.getText().toString();
                String inch = et6.getText().toString();
                String weyt = et3.getText().toString();
                String age = et4.getText().toString();
                String gender = et5.getText().toString();
                String intento = res.getText().toString();
                String meseg = msg2.getText().toString();

                if ( ( et.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))) {
                    et.setError("Please enter your name");
                    et.requestFocus();

                }
                else if ( ( et2.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))) {
                    et2.setError("Please enter your Height!");
                    et2.requestFocus();

                }
                else if ( ( et6.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))) {
                    et6.setError("Please enter your Height!");
                    et6.requestFocus();

                }
                else if ( ( et3.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))) {
                    et3.setError("Please enter your Weight!");
                    et3.requestFocus();
                }

                else if ( ( et4.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))) {
                    et4.setError("Please enter your Age!");
                    et4.requestFocus();
                }

               else if ( ( et5.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))) {
                    et5.setError("Please enter your Gender!");
                    et5.requestFocus();
                }

                else{
                    double weight;
                    double inches;
                    double height;
                    double feet1;
                    double bmi;
                    String msg="";

                    feet1 = Double.parseDouble(et2.getText().toString());
                    inches = Double.parseDouble(et6.getText().toString());
                    weight = Double.parseDouble(et3.getText().toString());

                    feet1 = feet1 * 12;
                    inches = feet1 + inches;
                    bmi = (weight * 2.2 / (inches * inches))* 703;

                    if (bmi < 16) {
                        msg = "Severely Underweight";
                    } else if (bmi < 18.5) {
                        msg = "Underweight";

                    } else if (bmi < 25) {
                        msg = "Normal";

                    } else if (bmi < 30) {
                        msg = "Overweight";

                    } else {
                        msg = "Obese";
                    }
                    Intent intent = new Intent(newprofile.this,result.class);
                    res.setText(String.format("%.1f",bmi));
                    qwe.setText(String.format("%.2f",bmi));
                    view_msg.setText(msg);
                    msg2.setText(String.valueOf(msg));

                    intent.putExtra("user",name);
                    intent.putExtra("result",meseg);
                    intent.putExtra("height",feet);
                    intent.putExtra("inch",inch);
                    intent.putExtra("weight",weyt);
                    intent.putExtra("age",age);
                    intent.putExtra("gender",gender);
                    intent.putExtra("intenti",intento);

                    startActivity(intent);
                }
```

This is the second activity xml

```js
 TextView nameView= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView8);
        TextView bmiView= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.insertbmi);
        TextView bmibmi= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resulta);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String bmishow = intent.getStringExtra("intenti");
        bmiView.setText(bmishow);

        String bmicheck = intent.getStringExtra("result");
        bmibmi.setText(bmicheck);

        String name = intent.getStringExtra("user");
        nameView.setText(name);
```

Sorry for my bad coding :<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data passing from activity to activity is correct, but your variables are not correct. Change this line:

```
intent.putExtra("result",meseg);
```

To this:

```
intent.putExtra("result",msg);
```

Also your code looks good but you could use more verbose variable names: msg -> message. It doesn't hurt :)

Comment: thanks it worked! but the calculated bmi doesn't show, the one that should be shown to another activity getExtra ("intenti")